# Is there any function which returns True if an element is the last element in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any function which returns `True` if an element is the last element in the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use equality and item access; negative indices give you items counting from the end:

```
some_list[-1] == element
```

This expression is `True` when the last item in `some_list` and the value referenced by  `element` are equal.

Demo:

```
>>> lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> lst[-1] == 'foo'
False
>>> lst[-1] == 'baz'
True
```

If `element` could be in the list more than once and you only want `True` if it is the very last item in the list, and doesn't occur anywhere else, then test for that explicitly:

```
some_list[-1] == element and some_list.index(element) == len(some_list) - 1
```

This works because if there is more than one occurrence of `element` in `some_list`, the `list.index()` method would find a lower index than `len(some_list)`. The expression strikes a balance between performance and the requirement to scan for other occurrences; there is no need to scan the whole list if the `some_list[-1] == element` test failed.

Comment: This just checks if the values match the value of the last element. not if that elements is actually the last element in the list. You could have a list where that value occurs more than once.

Comment: @M4rtini: There, added an additional test to verify that `element` occurs only once; it should short-circuit as early as possible if not, so I used `list.index()` rather than `list.count()` or slicing.

Comment: You could check the object reference, some_list[-1] is element, but not foolproof since different objects could reference the same place. x = ['foo', 'foo'],  x[0] is x[1] gives true :/

Comment: @M4rtini: That is something **different**. The fact that short strings are interned in CPython is an implementation detail. In any case, object identity also means object equality, which is what we are testing for here. If you wanted to test for object identity, you'd use `is` instead of `==`.